# Cannot use mongoosastic functions .x is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoosastic

I tried to add mongoosastic @types with npm but that did not work, how could I make it recognize the functions? (.search() does not work either)

Error described by  VS Code:

module "c:/Users/joche/Desktop/Proyectos/E-Commerce/Backend/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic"
Could not find a declaration file for module 'mongoosastic'. 'c:/Users/joche/Desktop/Proyectos/E-Commerce/Backend/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/mongoosastic` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mongoosastic';`ts(7016)

Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/gaminghard", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type:String, es_indexed:true },
    category: String,
    brand: String,
    model: { type:String, es_indexed:true },
    desc: { type:String, es_indexed:true },
    price: Number,
    stock: Number,
    weight: Number,
    img: String,
    quantityToBuy: Number
},
{
    collection: 'Products'
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    hosts: [
        "localhost:9200"
    ]
});

Product.createMapping(function(err, mapping){
    if(err){
        console.log("error creating mapping");
        console.log("err");
    }else{
        console.log("Mapping successfully created");
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started listening on port 3000");
});
```

Nodemon error:

```
C:\Users\joche\Desktop\Proyectos\E-Commerce\Backend\server.js:60
Product.createMapping(function(err, mapping){
        ^

TypeError: Product.createMapping is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joche\Desktop\Proyectos\E-Commerce\Backend\server.js:60:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jose Ignacio Carbone",
  "license": "No license - private",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.32",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoosastic": "^4.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.12",
  }
}
```

Edit: Tried adding .d.ts file, VS Code error was gone but still couldn't compile the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer here, had to move

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    hosts: [
        "localhost:9200"
    ]
});

Above

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);

Because I then use Product without the plugin previously applied, which does not make sense.